# Model question in MVC3

Tags: database-design, asp.net-mvc-3, class-design, ef-code-first, models

I have a basic question in MVC3. I am starting to write out Models for my project. I understand Models are in a way tables in my relational database layer. How do I specify a class attribute (field in a table) as  a FK. I know the [Key] qualifier for PKs. For example :

```
 public class Class1
{
    [Key]
    public int MyID { get; set; }
    public string myDes {get;set;}

}
```

In the above example MyId is a PK in Class1. How do I use this MyId in a another class and use it as FK.

EDIT: Is this correct?

```
public class Class2
```

{
    [Key]
    public int SecondID { get; set; }

```
[ForeignKey("MyId")]
public string MyId{ get; set; }
```

}

Class1 and Class2 are in two different .cs files.

Comment: What or/m are you using?

Comment: @david : Nhibernate is what we intend to use in future.. for now, I am just starting to learn the basics. For now, I guess I am using the whatever that is built in the VS environment in MVC3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store an instance of the associated record (or a list of associated records for one-to-many or many-to-many relationships).

```
public MyOtherObject MyObject { get; set; }
```

This may change based how you are persisting the data to the DB, but in general this is the OO way to do it.

I do this using EF 4.1 Code First, and the resulting DB contains a Foreign Key into the associated table.

---

**Edit in response to your latest comment (regarding the ForeignKeyAttribute) so I can use the better code formatting in the answer:**

According to the MSDN entry for the `ForeignKeyAttribute` ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.103).aspx#Y198](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.foreignkeyattribute%28v=vs.103%29.aspx#Y198)), the name you pass into the `ForeignKeyAttribute` is the name of the corresponding navigation property or foreign key property *on the same class.*

For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    // This is a "Navigation Property"
    public MyOtherClass ForeignObject { get; set; }

    // This is a "Foreign Key Property"
    [ForeignKey("ForeignObject")]
    public int ForeignObjectID { get; set; }
}
```

The `ForeignKey` attribute in the above code snippet identifies the `ForeignObjectID` property as a foreign key for the `ForeignObject` property.  You will still need an instance of the foreign object in your class.

You can also use the `ForeignKey` attribute on the navigation property, just pass in the name of the foreign key property to the attribute:

```
public class MyClass
{
    // This is a "Navigation Property"
    [ForeignKey("ForeignObjectID")]
    public MyOtherClass ForeignObject { get; set; }

    // This is a "Foreign Key Property"
    public int ForeignObjectID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So if I want to use a PK in Class1 as FK in Class2, you are saying, I write Public Class1 class1{get;set;} in the class definition of Class2?

Comment: Keep in mind that I answered this question without knowing what ORM you are using (NHibernate according to your other comment), so this may be different.  I'm not familiar with NHibernate.

Comment: Will this work even if the class definitions are in two different .cs files within the same namespace.

Comment: I am using EF too for now. Thank you

Comment: basically it is this.. in a standard MVC3 project, there is a account models class with membership information... I want to link the username in that .cs file to classes in other .cs files so Users can be linked up to appropriate records..

Comment: Create your classes/objects like you normally would; Separate files are fine.  When you actually start mapping your objects is when you specify things like keys (pk & fk).  The dataannotations you used above is specific to EF.

Comment: Yeah, Separate files are fine.  Even separate namespaces will work too.  EF Code First will generate the database for you based on your class definitions, including the keys.

Comment: [ForeignKey("MyId")] if I write this in class2 def, will this not work... assuming MyId is an attribute from a class1 in different .cs file. so class1 will have [Key]
    public int MyID { get; set; } and class2 will have  [ForeignKey("MyId")].. is this correct?

Comment: @ZVenue See my edit in response to your question about the `ForeignKeyAttribute`